# create a trigger on a view

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a time-dependent view that uses the `now()` function and hence changes values with the passage of time.

Simplistic code below:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS av;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
CREATE TABLE A (when_epoch_seconds INTEGER, x VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO A(when_epoch_seconds, x) SELECT CAST (EXTRACT (epoch FROM now()) AS INT), 'x';

CREATE VIEW av AS
WITH cte AS
(SELECT MAX(when_epoch_seconds) AS latestEntry FROM a)
SELECT CAST (EXTRACT (epoch FROM now()) AS INT) - cte.latestEntry > 5 AS too_old FROM cte;

SELECT too_old FROM av;
```

My question is how can I create a trigger that continuously monitors the value of column `too_old` in view `av` and, e.g., inserts a row in a "notifications" table whenever that value flips from true to false or vice-versa? Or is there maybe some other mechanism that's more suited to accomplishing the same effect?

Comment: Triggers are only run when DML on the table is executed. There is no such thing as a trigger that "*continuously monitors*" something. You might be looking for listen/notify though: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html

Comment: The thing is you do not need something to happen upon INSERT on table A, but when for more than 5 seconds there was **not** an INSERT on that table. There is no way to achieve that with PostgreSQL only, you need to run a cron job that checks the condition on every second.

Answer (score 1):

A [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29) is a "virtual" table, meaning that it reflects the values stored into one or more tables. A [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) is a set of instructions that are executed when a specific event (INSERT, DELETE, etc) happens on a table.

> how can I create a trigger that continuously monitors the value of
>   column too_old in view av

You can't create a trigger related to a view. A view doesn't "change" values, a table does. A view is only a result set of records stored into the referencing table(s). **EDIT**: You can actually create a view (as @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' precisely said), [in PostgreSQL 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html). It is a feature introduced in the latest versions of the engine. Even if you can create a trigger on a view, I think the most correct way is to create it on the base table. I don't see actually the point in creating it on a view.

It doesn't exist a trigger that is always executed, listening for changes of referencing table. If it would be existing, a trigger that runs continuously will affect terribly the performance of your SQL engine, making your SQL engine sluggish and incredibly slow running the queries. That, I think, is the main reason why such thing doesn't exist.

The PostgreSQL engine has a nice feature that could help you, listening for changes, named indeed [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html).

Comment: Based on what I've read, the `NOTIFY` / `LISTEN` mechanism doesn't address the core of the issue I'm facing. *Something* would have to invoke `NOTIFY` and that *something* would need to be continuously monitoring the view to detect any changes. So it would seem that the only way to do that is with an external cron job or some other external client. Unless there is some other support for long-running daemon/service-like server-side code in PostgreSQL.

Comment: *"You can't create a trigger related to a view."* [You can create triggers on views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html).